# What is the scope of variables, declared in a "for" condition?

Tags: c, c11

```
void main(void){
    for(int i;;);
    for(int i;;);
}
```

Is this valid C code? What is the scope of i?

Comment: *Some* compiler might consider that to be invalid code, as there are 2 infinite loops which makes the second one unreachable.

Comment: "Is this valid C code?" - `void main(void)` support is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C99 6.8.5.3 *The for statement*

> The statement

```
for (clause-1 ;expression-2 ;expression-3 )statement
```

> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. **If clause-1is a
>   declaration, the scope of any variables it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
>   the entire loop, including the other two expressions;** it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.

Also note that this feature is valid only since C99. In other words, you can't declare variable in the first statement in `for` loop in C89.